# How to group Column Data with like Name to find Sum, min, and max?

Tags: python, r, excel, vba, data-science

I'm importing a csv file that contains transposed data. The data has columns in the following format: AC1,AC2,AD1,AD2,BP1,BP2,CT1,CO1,CO2,CS1,etc

What I've been hoping to accomplish is to group together and find the SUM of each LIKE column heading along with the min and max of each of those newly grouped columns.

Example would be:

```
AC1+AC2 = AC(sum), min, max

AD1+AD2 = AD(sum), min, max

BP1+BP2 = BP(sum), min, max
```

Format and structure do not matter as long as the end result works.

Is this feasibly possible or is there a better approach that can be taken to achieve this?

I've used macros via Excel and there still requires a bit manual effort to group the data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the column names follow the pattern in your example - a common prefix of letters followed by numbers - you can use this approach.

Example data:

```
set.seed(1001)
df1 <- data.frame(AC1 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  AC2 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  AD1 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  AD2 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  BP1 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE),
                  BP2 = sample(1:100, 50, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Code. Create a new variable on which to group by removing the numbers from the variable name:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  gather(Var, Val) %>% 
  mutate(Var2 = gsub("\\d+", "", Var)) %>% 
  group_by(Var2) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(Val, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Min = min(Val, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Max = max(Val, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Var2    Sum   Min   Max
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 AC     4846     1   100
2 AD     4924     4    96
3 BP     5000     1   100
```

Comment: Thanks @neilfws this was more informative and helpful than I anticipated. It's fulfilling knowing that the solution was possible. I played around and modified bits and pieces and got pretty close to where I need to be. I added in an export to a newly created dataframe with the results that I needed in case anyone else is looking to do the same.

write.table(df2 , file = "pathame\file.csv")

Comment: You can replace redundant sampling with `as.data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 50 * 6, TRUE), 50))` :)